# Calculate the number of rows where value is smaller than a respective next offset value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset, countif

I'm trying to create an Excel-formula that counts the number of times a labeled value is smaller than another value offset down respectively to itself. The image below shows a dataset (left), and a matrix with the labels and offset values (top right). The values E3:H7 are the desired results (plus "/" followed by the number of occurences).

Example E3 means: 4/4 times, value A was SMALLER THAN the next value offset by 1 (a.k.a. the next B).

Another example G4: 2/4 times, value B was SMALLER THAN the next value offset by 3 (a.k.a. the next E)

[image]

It would be a combination of COUNTIF and OFFSET i believe, but Matrix-calculations and offset don't seem to work together. I hope anyone can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The final formula in E3 (for the value in front of the slash):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1*($B$1:$B$20<OFFSET($B$1:$B$20,E$2,0))),1*($A$1:$A$20=$D3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a compound problem to count both the values less than the other values as offsets, and to count the pairs of values being compared.

If you use this formula in Cell E3 and then copy/paste down and across, it should do the trick (the named range `Labels` is `$A$1:$A$20` and the range `Values` is `$B$1:$B$20`):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Values<OFFSET(Values,E$2,0))*(Labels=$D7))&"/"&SUMPRODUCT(--(Labels=$D7)*--(OFFSET(Labels,E$2,0)=OFFSET($D7,E$2,0)))
```